# Where can I find information about monthly seasonal change in a given area?

Tags: meteorology, climate, seasons

I have searched Google for almost an hour with no result. I'm looking for something like, "Indonesia, January to August is rain season, September to December is hot season".

I can't use the old information in books about seasonal change that now seem to have shifted and I can't find any updated information anywhere.

Comment: Have you read the [Climate of Indonesia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Climate_of_Indonesia) page on Wikipedia?

Comment: have you looked at the websites of your meteorological service,where i live they have statistics for every meteorological station in the country and often even for other countries.

Comment: some thing similar to this https://www.yr.no/place/Norway/Oslo/Oslo/Oslo/statistics.html one can search by date and get climate data for a long period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [climatemps.com](http://www.climatemps.com/) for easy access and plots. There they have a map you can click on or a list by countries.
More data and analysis tools are available at the [KNMI Climate Explorer](https://climexp.knmi.nl/selectstation.cgi?id=d17099be003bf17970040ea12c50ad61), a more reliable and scientifically sound source.

This is one of the outputs for Jakarta from [jakarta.climatemps.com](http://www.jakarta.climatemps.com/)

[image]